# Performance Enhancement in Orbeon Forms

Tags: orbeon, xforms

I have a set of 10 controls in a single page.
When i am entering one field, a 'Loading.....' symbol occurs on the top of the page.
But still i am able to edit the other fields in the same page.

Is there any methods (or) functions in Orbeon which will blur all other fields when one field is entered with the values?
So that no field will be editable.

For Eg:when some pop-windows opens all other fields at the back will be made blurred and non-editable.
Similarly it must be for fields in the same page

Answer (score 0):

There is no way, out-of-the-box, to "blur" all the other fields while a user is entering data in one field.

The *Loading* indicator tells users that information is being exchanged between the browser and the server in the background, just as if you had an indication "Autosaving…", but I don't really see why or in which situation preventing the user from filling out another field while this is happening would be useful. (This is somewhat off-topic, purely based on your question, but if you have feedback on this, feel free to leave a comment below.)

Comment: Hi,thanks for replying.Here is my situation,If i have 3 fields of which one is a textbox which will be populated with value when a button is clicked which will fetch the value from a webservice and Other 2 fields are checkboxes,So what happens is that,when the webservice call is made by clicking the button,"Loading..." symbol occurs.So at that time, i want that the checkboxes to be made un-editable.

Comment: @LavanyaG I now understand, and this makes sense. Do you need those 2 other fields to be writable at all? If not, you can make them always read-only, which would solve the problem. Otherwise, this would be doable by writing XForms, but isn't supported out-of-the-box by the forms generated by Form Builder. I created an RFE for this here: https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/1411